# Bring validation rule to VS Code project

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, validation-rule, sandbox, vs-code

I am new to Salesforce and I have a question regarding to my first real task so I don’t make nothing wrong.

I have created a new validation rule in my sandbox and I want to bring this to my Visual Studio project so I can create a pull request after that. I am already connected with my sandbox and already created a new branch. How I bring this change now to VS Code? I can see that the other validation rules from the project are here but I’m not sure how to bring mine and I’m afraid to try different things here.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, no worries, I also suggest you look into this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/org-browser) to add into @sfdcfox mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the validation rules folder for the object, and click SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox!!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve validation rules under each Object by clicking on the cloud icon as shown on the picture bellow:

[image]

They will be shown inside each separate Object under `validationRules` folder

[image]